# form is causing page scroll

Tags: javascript, forms, scroll

I have an embedded form that is causing the page to scroll down and then back up again. How do I prevent the page from scrolling up and down?

This is what the form code looks like:

```html
<script>
  var SmartDONORCOVEROLXSettings = {
    "product": "SmartDONORCOVEROLX",
    "prompt": "Check this box to continue.",
    "summary": "Pay full amount.",
    "hideOther": false,
    "disableTimer": false,
    "flatFeeMode": false,
    "defaulton": false,
    "addtopaymentmethods": false,
    "variable": 2.598,
    "fixed": 0.26
  }
</script>
<script src="https://us.smartthing.org/download/file.php?jsformat=1&amp;olx=1&amp;f=-js.html&amp;c=jfarthing@emilyk.org&amp;k=iE5RQ9H1VAAuapC"></script>
```

I've tried adding in the head/body but that doesn't work. Would a `defer` work?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I would imagine the scrolling behaviour is part of the embedded script you're using. As such, unless the scroll can be toggled on/off by one of the configuration properties in `SmartDONORCOVEROLXSettings `, then there's very little you can do to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: _"this is what the form code looks like"_ - that is clearly _not_ "form code", but the embedding of a JavaScript. But plugging that into a jsfiddle does not appear to cause anything at all to happen, https://jsfiddle.net/26Lph9qa/ - so we need a lot more info from your here, how this is supposed to work, resp. a _proper_ [mre].